# How to get the pointers to an id variable and an NSObject pointer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macos

```
id        idPointer = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
NSObject *nsPointer = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
```

How do I get the pointers of `idPointer` and `nsPointer`?

Comment: these **are** actually pointers

Comment: Yes, but I want the pointers to them!

Comment: never, never, never put the correct answer as a comment.... ;)

Comment: No, you should learn from Joe ;)

Comment: what do you want me to learn from Joe ?

Comment: To put the correct answer as an answer and not as a comment ;)

Comment: that's right, I hope that you at least voted up my comment, lol ;)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Save for NSError, pointers to pointers to objects (pass by reference) just isn't a pattern used in objective-c regularly.

Comment: Vince: Do you actually get points when your comment get upvoted? if so, how much?
bbum: I'm not that familiar with objective-c and I wanted to see what happend when assigning pointers during deep copying of array objects.

Comment: no, no bonus, and it was actually a joke, but thanks for voting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get pointers to pointers it just requires an extra `*` on the variable. And to assign them you will usually get the address of a normal pointer `&`. And then dereference them again with `*` in front.

```
//Declare and Assign them
id       *idPointerPointer = &idPointer;
NSObject **nsPointerPointer = &nsPointer;

//Dereference them (just an example to send a message)
[*idPointerPointer release];
[*nsPointerPointer release];
```

Comment: Great! How do I print them using NSLog? 
NSLog(@"%@", idPointerPointer); doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It is just an address to an address, Here is how you can log the 2 pointer values and then the object itself NSLog(@"id*<%p> id<%p> value: %@", idPointerPointer, *idPointerPointer, *idPointerPointer);

Comment: I assume you mean NSLog(@"id*<%p> id<%p> value: %@", idPointerPointer, *nsPointerPointer, *idPointerPointer); ?

Comment: No the first example was just for idPointerPointer, the first one prints the address of idPointerPointer, the next prints the address that idPointerPointer is pointing to and then the next prints the description of what it is pointing at is pointing at. o.O